# Can you built back muscles you have lost?

Tags: diet, muscle-mass, intermittent-fasting

I have read so much about diets that warning that not eating adequate amounts of protein will result in muscle loss. On the other hand I see people like Christian Bale almost flaunting this rule going up and down the built_rake-thin scale multiple times successfully.

Is it true that muscles lost is lost forever ? If so how do people like him do it ? When I see him in the Machinist I don't think his frame just shows water loss from muscles only right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you getting this information?

Unless you have some sort of muscular dystrophy, you can ALWAYS build muscle. It doesn't matter if you're building it for the first time, or re-building it for the tenth.

Why would lost muscle mass be lost forever?

Comment: That or if you've lost it for other reasons. My Mother-in-Law survived Stage 4 melanoma on her shoulder, and that shoulder muscle which was scooped out is never coming back.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Wow. But yeah, that's obviously not coming back anytime soon.

Comment: :) Sorry. Probably ought to have added an emoticon to indicate that I wasn't actually criticizing your answer, but making a sort of a joke on the multiple meanings of "losing" muscle.

Comment: Hehe, no I interpreted it as informal, so no worries there. I don't think you can fix **removed** muscle mass with exercise! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, you have the wrong information. The only truth is, you can build back your muscles. Big and extreme changes like those on Christian Bale are not good for health at all. If your body is constantly in shock, after some time it can become "stubborn" in terms of difficult weight gain/weight loss. That's why balance is the best solution for your body. If you've lost your muscles, just keep eating protein-rich foods and exercise. The changes will come soon.